# My Trackpad doesn't work on my MBP when I unpaired Logitech mouse

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I had Logitech mouse paired to my MBP/Capitan. I used Logitech Unifying Thing to unpair the mouse. Mistake: now no mouse, and no trackpad response. Keyboard still works. Rebooted MBP, no change. Is there a way to bring MBP trackpad back using only kybd?

Comment: Boot into safe mode.  The track pad should work.  Then uninstall the Logitech software

Comment: Booting into safe mode worked. Also discovered that simply removing the logitech dongle freed up the trackpad. Was able to run uninstaller successfully. (Now I can't re-pair them - opening another q for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Allan recommended booting into safe mode, so 3rd-party extensions wouldn't be loaded. This brought the trackpad back, and I was able to run the uninstaller.

I also found that merely unplugging the Logitech transceiver dongle freed the trackpad. No reboot needed.