# How do I re-pair Logitech mouse with MBP after uninstalling and reinstalling the Logitech Unifying Software

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I was using my MBP/Catalina with a logitech mouse and keyboard and the transceiver dongle, plugged into a USB port on a USB-to-Thunderbolt adapter. I wanted to make it ignore the mouse temporarily, so using the Logitech control panel I unpaired the mouse. Unfortunately the trackpad didn't come back, so I had no mouse control at all, even after rebooting.

As recommended [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392435/my-trackpad-doesnt-work-on-my-mbp-when-i-unpaired-logitech-mouse), I managed to reboot in safe mode which gave me the trackpad back, and I ran the Logitech Uninstaller. Rebooted normally, and trackpad worked. However, when I plug the dongle into the USB port, the trackpad stops working.

I tried reinstalling Logitech Unifying Spftware, but it won't proceed until I plug in the dongle, and when I do that, again the trackpad freezes!

Any ideas on solving this?

**UPDATE**: I confirmed - the trackpad freezes when I insert the transceiver in the USB port, *even after I ran the Uninstaller and rebooted.* This seems odd - but I don't know enough about USB to know what happens when you plug in something without its control software installed.

Does this sound more like a non-Logitech problem?

**UPDATE 2**: I discovered that the problem doesn't occur when I log in as my other userid.

**UPDATE 3**: The System Report/USB page identifies the Logitech receiver when it's plugged in, so it's obviously able to communicate with it.

**Now It Works**: What I did: switch to my alternate, "clean" user, and installed Logitech Unifying Software there. The mouse worked. Switched to primary user, where I've been having the issue, and installed Logitech Unifying Software there (for like the 4th time). Now the mouse works in the primary user.

Comment: I use Logitech products almost exclusively and haven’t run into this issue.  However, the only variable I’m not familiar with is this “USB to Thunderbolt” adapter.  Can you expand on this?  Brand, model, etc?

Comment: @Allan It's a "Twopan T1-H". It has 4 USB-2?3? ports and an HDMI port. It's plugged into one of the MBP's 4 Thunderbolt ports. I guess it could be USB-C and not Tbolt ??  Edit: I tried another USB/Thunderbolt hub and got the same result.

Comment: Never heard of those guys.  Try an [Anker](https://amzn.to/2MdCVIR), they use higher grade components than the off-brands.  Oh, and those are USB3 ports

Comment: Try resetting SMC or NVRAM/PRAM?

Comment: @Wynter I have reset both SMC and NVRAM, but there's no change. However, I notice that I can login as my other userid and the problem goes away. I will update my question.

Comment: If the problem goes away in the another User account, something is being loaded that's messing with it.  Do you have any USB software like [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com/) loaded?  What do you have in your Login Items?

Comment: @Allan - I removed all Login items from my user. I also ran `ps axww` and looked for anything with 'usb' or 'logitech' in the name but didn't see anything suspicious. Hm. I haven't had to deal with an extension conflict since Classic.

Comment: FWIW, I verified that the problem doesn't occur in the alternate user (which I keep clean for this purpose), *even when* the problem user is logged in but switched out.

Comment: It may not be ideal, but if the problem seems to persist, perhaps just migrate all your data and applications to a new user account? At least you wouldn't have to reinstall macOS.